How can I control the dns query of an nginx proxy_pass setup on a ubuntu server?
I'm getting a "502 Bad Gateway" error after configuring a public proxy to a private web app running on localhost.
The nginx error log shows:
2024/08/15 13:56:18 [error] 17674#17674: *3 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error:SSL alert number 80) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.19.113, server: testserver.home.private, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "testserver.home.private"
The problem is the upstream directive from the nginx config is this:
proxy_pass              https://app.internal:8081;
The app in question requires access by hostname and not ip address.  manually navigating to https://app.internal:8081 from a terminal works fine while using the ip address fails.
The /etc/hosts file on the server maps app.internal to 127.0.0.1 correctly.
I'm concerned that if nginx is doing the resolving itself and getting an ip address that the proxy call will never work.  Is there a way to turn off nginx dns queries so that the nginx proxy queries a domain name and not an ip address?

You need to pass the Host header so the app knows to respond to the app.internal. Depending on the server you are proxying to, you may need additional headers to make this work.
Here is a simple nginx server block that shows adding the header:
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  app.public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app.internal:8081/;
        proxy_set_header Host "app.internal";
    }
}

For more details:

Nginx: when to use proxy_set_header Host $host vs $proxy_host
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header


I appreciate this and it does appear that this should fix it, but after adding the Host header I got no change in behavior.  The log still shows the ip, so I can't confirm it is behaving like I need it to.

The app required an additional setting.
I needed:
proxy_ssl_server_name   on;
Not sure if it is in addition to the Host header you mentioned.
